# What is the data type of this.loginForm.value?

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to use a service but I get this error:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'Partial<{ email: string | null; password:
> string | null; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Login'.
> Types of property '"email"' are incompatible.
> Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

**Service**

```js
public login(data: Login): Observable<string> {
  return this.httpClient.post<string>(environment.apiUrl + '/login', data);
}
```

**Interface**

```js
export interface Login {
  "email": string,
  "password": string
}
```

**Component**

```js
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm = this.fb.group({
    'email': ['', [Validators.email, Validators.required]],
    'password': ['', Validators.required]
  })

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  submit() {
    this.loginService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(response => {
      // Do sumth
    })
  }

}
```

Is there something wrong with my interface, or should the parameter `data` have another data type?

Comment: 1. remove Partial, or add Partial to the type of data. 2. the data you are passing might be null, fix that

Answer (score 2):

Use `getRawValue()` to bypass possible undefined fields

```
this.loginService.login(this.loginForm.getRawValue()).subscribe(response => {
      // Do sumth
    })
```

Comment: I get the same error message.

Comment: I have tried in stackblit it's not throwing https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mgywft?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @Reem, you need to replace `this.fb.group` with `this.fb.nonNullable.group`

Answer (score 0):

As @nullptr suggested, the correct way to handle this is to use TypeScript type narrowing:

```
  submit() {
    if (this.loginForm.value && typeof this.loginForm.value.email !== 'undefined' && this.loginForm.value.email !== null) {
      this.loginService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(response => {
        // Do sumth
      })
    }

  }
```

There might be a shorthand way but I've chosen to be explicit.

Comment: I did the same but I still get that error.

Comment: Ah ok, did the best I could without a stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotations for interface variables.

```
export interface Login {
  email: string,
  password: string
}
```

also

```
    submit() {
    if (this.loginForm.value && typeof this.loginForm.value.email !== 'undefined' && this.loginForm.value.email !== null) {
      this.loginService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(response => {
        // Do sumth
      })
    }

  }
```

Comment: I did the same but I still get that error.

Comment: @Reem try email: string | undefined, password: string | undefined

Answer (score -2):

you can simply cast the value as the expected type, but I would make sure your form is valid first!

```js
submit() {
  this.loginForm.markAllAsTouched();
  if (this.loginForm.valid) {
    this.loginService.login((this.loginForm.value as Login)).subscribe(response => {
      // Do sumth
    })
  } else {
    // handle invalid form
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this in your service:

```
    login(data:any):Observable<any>{
         let json = JSON.stringify(data);
         let params = 'json='+json;
         let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
         return this._http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/login', params, {headers: headers});
}
```

Try this in your component:

```
submit() {
this.loginService.login(this.loginForm).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
})
```

Comment: This is the fourth time you've answered in Spanish, despite having seen interventions on each occasion - please desist! Posts are required to be in English here.